# Unable to call xsl file for my XML sitemap

Tags: xslt

I am trying to set up an XML sitemap, but it's not happening properly since it seems that [my xsl style sheet is not getting called](http://www.formationweb.net/sitemap.xml).

Earlier, I [had a problem](http://www.formationweb.net/test.xml) with my xml file on shortcodes and I had to wrap

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.formationweb.net/style.xsl"?>`

to

`<? echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.formationweb.net/style.xsl"?>'; ?>`

to avoid a parse error message. Not sure if they are related, but thought to mention.

I should get a properly formatted XML here : http://www.formationweb.net/sitemap.xml.

Thanks for any help. 
Best.

Comment: What? you need to rephrase your question, it is not readable

Answer (score 1):

Your sitemap should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
  xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

<url>
  <loc>http://www.formationweb.net/cours-intensif.php</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

So what you are currently returning is not a valid sitemap

Comment: You are sure Nrathaus ? I have one line more than your code, line that calls the stylesheet, and this code has worked for me earlier for a different website hosted in the same server !

Comment: It should be an XML not a Stylesheet, why you are mixing the two is not clear, you can use XSLT to make the XML into something readable (for humans), but sitemap.xml is supposed to be an XML

Comment: See here http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html it clearly states the XML structure, and it is quite strict on what can be found in it

Comment: Nowhere in the XSD says `xml-stylesheet` is allowed

Comment: Nrathaus, we are allowed to call xsl stylesheets from our XML files to make them human readable. See this page : http://www.offshoreeninde.fr/sitemap.xml. However, this was not my original question :)

Comment: If you insist, at least make it into two separate lines, so it looks the same, and fix this error "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: Nrathaus, calling an XSL stylesheet from an XML document to make that human readable is valid and is widely used.

However, this was not my question, my problem exists with or without that line. I thank you for your time nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I found this in my htaccess. Removed the .xml from there and this solved the issue :)

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html .shtml .xml
```